# Which method should I call to get title of the editor in c# Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mobile-application

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            var diary = new List<DiaryProperties>();
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(App.FolderPath, "*.notes.txt");
            foreach(var filename in files)
            {
                diary.Add(new DiaryProperties 
                {
                    //all properties are defined in the Models folder.
                    Filename=filename,
                    //Title=how to get title ??? 
                    Text=File.ReadAllText(filename),
                    Date=File.GetCreationTime(filename)
                });
            }
            listview.ItemsSource = diary.OrderBy(d => d.Date).ToList();
        }
```

```
//xaml code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyDiary.AddNewNote"
             Title="Add New Note">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="+" 
                     Clicked="OnSaveClickedButton"/>
        <ToolbarItem Grid.Column="1"
                     Text="*"
                     Clicked="OnDeleteClickedButton"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="20">
            <Editor Placeholder="Title"
                    PlaceholderColor="#000"
                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                    HeightRequest="50"/>
            <Editor Placeholder="Enter Your Note"
                    Text="{Binding Text}"
                    AutoSize="TextChanges"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I've defined all properties in Model Folder, I've to get title in listview, If I'm calling same functions ReadAllText, all content is showing in spite of title. I've edited it with xaml code. please check it again

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyDiary.MyNotes"
             Title="My Notes">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="+"
                     Clicked="OnNoteAddedClicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ListView x:Name="listview"
              Margin="20"
              ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                               FontSize="18"
                               TextColor="#f35e20" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}"
                               FontSize="15"
                               TextColor="#503026" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Date}"
                               FontSize="15"
                               TextColor="#503026" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

the above code is to show the items in listview, and this is the core page of the application.

```
public AddNewNote()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        async void OnSaveClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Diary = (DiaryProperties)BindingContext;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Diary.Filename))
            {
                //save
                var filename = Path.Combine(App.FolderPath, $"{Path.GetRandomFileName()}.notes.txt");
                File.WriteAllText(filename, Diary.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                //update
                File.WriteAllText(Diary.Filename, Diary.Text);
            }

            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
```

Above code is to save the new note, as you said, kindly let me know what should I have to do to make the first line as the title. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "Title"?  A file does not have a "Title" property.

Comment: is the Title the first line of the file?

Comment: I've defined two editors in .xaml file, one is for the title and another for the text. for the text, I'm using File.ReadAllText. I want to know how to read or get the title.

Comment: please show the XAML

Comment: I updated my question with xaml code please check it again. thanks

Comment: `Text="{Binding Title}"` - you are using data binding so you should be able to get the title from the `Title` property of your model.  There is no `ListView` on this page - is the `OnAppearing` you posted for a different page?

Comment: There are two xaml pages one is to display listview items and another for adding new item. I posted xaml for adding a new item, let me show you the xaml for displaying listview item.

Comment: if you are saving your data to file, you will need to figure out some mechanism to store the Title.  You would serialize your model to json instead of just writing a text file, or you could store the Title as the first line of the file, etc.

Comment: can you tell me how to store the title as the first line of the file, as I'm new to xamarin

Comment: this is basic C#.  If you are already writing to the note text to a file, just do the same with the title.  If you need specific help, please post the code you have for saving the note

Comment: I have posted the code to save a new note

Answer (score 1):

just append `Title` to the beginning of your data

```
string data = Diary.Title + Environment.Newline;
data += Diary.Text;
File.WriteAllText(filename, data);
```